# why not session data is stored in table duration do login in site?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-cookies, session-timeout

I am New Comer in PHP with MVC Codeigniter Framework.
I have a issue about session storing in table(ci_sessions) with codeigniter.and i have also set config.php file like-

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']= 3600;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']= TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']= 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']= FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

and also created table namely ci_sessions in database. like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
user_data text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

After doing all activities of the above ,No data stored in user_data column of ci_sessions table in DB.

When I want to access session data by using like- 
`print_r($this->session->all_userdata());`
`print $this->session->userdata['myksb'];`

then error is displayed like -

```
Array ( 
[session_id] => 97b9e34713b52f32a32e915053cba826
[ip_address] => 127.0.0.1 
[user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko 
[last_activity] => 1363866927 ) 

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: myksb
Filename: controllers/home.php
Line Number: 13876
```

Comment: Did you load the session library? (`$this->load->library('session');` or autoload)

Comment: Thanks Mr. Maxime Morin for reponse. I have include this statement like -   $this->load->library('session'); in costructor of controller

Comment: Have you assigned data to that key?

Comment: Yes Sir , I have assigned data to that key like - $this->session->set_userdata('myksb','chandan'); during session creation in any function.

Comment: Use `$this->session->userdata('myksb');`.  `userdata()` is a method not an array.  Although, it will print empty because it's obviously not in your session...

Comment: If i am using $this->session->userdata('myksb'); then it will print empty. Please help me.... what should i do to solve it....

Comment: @ChandanSroniyan Please show us the code where you add set your user's data.  (`$this->session->set_userdata('myksb','chandan');`)  I'm not sure what you meant by "during the session creation in any function".  On a side note, make sure you don't destroy the session before printing the results.

Comment: //Logic for demo session start here
`function sessionDemo()
{
$this->session->sess_destroy();
$this->session->set_userdata('myksb','chandan');
redirect('home/sessionDemo1');
}
function sessionDemo1()
{
print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
print $this->session->userdata('myksb');
die;
}`
//Logic for demo session end here

Comment: Did you try without the `$this->session->sess_destroy();` call?  `sess_destroy()` kills your session then you want to add data to your session.  Doesn't it sounds wrong? ... Stop with the "please help me" it's only adding noise to your question...

Comment: @Maxime Morin , a error occurs like -  Fatal error: Call to undefined function sess_destroy() in C:\wamp\www\mysadagi_voicetongues\system\application\controllers\home.php on line 13866

Comment: See my answer, you have to remove the whole line. (`$this->session->sess_destroy();`)

Comment: Very-Very Thank Mr.Maxime Morin. My Problem has been solved.

Comment: If your problem was solved by my answer below, feel free to accept it.  If your problem was solved by doing something else, please add an answer and accept it.

Comment: my problem was solved by @Maxime Morin .thanks

Answer (score 1):

These a couple things to be fixed here.

1. `$this->session->userdata()` is a method not an array. `$this->session->userdata['myksb'];` is not valid.  You have to use `$this->session->userdata('myksb');`
2. `$this->session->sess_destroy()` kills your session.  It actually removes your sessionId from your session and cookie.  Once that is done, you can not assign new information to your session, it doesn't have an ID anymore.  You have to remove that call.  CodeIgniter will automatically clean your session table.